# How do I make a webapp open link inside the webapp instead of safari

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, mobile-safari

So I am iFraming another site and I want my users to Add the Site to the homescreen and use it from there. But when I try using codes from other sites, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Include these meta tags in the `<head>` of your `index.html` file. On iOS, this will simulate a webapp that can be added to the home screen.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="AppTitle">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/launch.png">
```

In order to have the icon and the launch image load correctly for each device, your images must have the exact dimensions described in Apple's UI Guide linked below. If the images are not specified with these dimensions, it will not load.

[Launch Screen Dimensions](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/#static-launch-screen-images)

[App Icon Dimensions](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/#app-icon-sizes)

[Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

This Gist also shows all available meta tags: https://gist.github.com/tfausak/2222823

Comment: that wasnt what i was asking because i can get the first page to be a webapp but when i tap a link on the iframed webapp it loads it onto safari